# In the Firebase node client, is ref.off an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

```
var ref = new Firebase('somefirebaseinstace.io/abc');

ref.off('value');
```

is `ref.off` above an asynchrous function? The documentation is not very clear on this. (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/off.html).

Comment: It doesn't take any completion callbacks (the callback you can optionally pass to it is to unsubscribe a particular callback function that was previously registered using `.on()`), so I would guess it isn't.

Comment: You're right @robertklep. But I get the feeling that the question is about something else. Amal: f you're having a problem, please share what you're trying to do and what unexpected behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Neither `on` or `off` are by themselves asynchronous. The callback you pass into `on` is called asynchronously (and likely repeatedly). But since you don't specify a callback to `off`, there's nothing that happens asynchronously there.